# Admin creating users under devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Rials 4.2 application with devise 3.5 where user creation limited to two types of users (identified by boolean values).  Pundit is used for authorization, but NOT invoked the User class.

Routes defines

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
resources :users do
  collection do
    get :index_context
  end
end
```

A registrations_controller sets up private methods to define `sign_up_params` and `account_update_params` => `params.require(:user).permit(   ...`

Applications_controller authenticates from token

```
def authenticate_user_from_token!
  user_email = request.headers["X-API-EMAIL"].presence
  user_auth_token = request.headers["X-API-TOKEN"].presence
  user = user_email && User.find_by_email(user_email)

  if user && Devise.secure_compare(user.authentication_token, user_auth_token)
    sign_in(user, store: false)
  end
end
```

Given the context, the attempt is to override devise by having a sessions_controller

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:create, :new]
    skip_authorization_check only: [:create, :failure, :show_current_user, :options, :new]
```

But when a user that is enabled to create users submits the record

```
Started POST "/users" for [...]
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
```

just as if the user would go to address `/users/sign_in`

Thus somehow the request is being captured by Devise's handling, notwithstanding the session controller's before filter.  How can this be overcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After perusing various options like overriding the RegistrationsController, but simply creating a separate action, with relevant authorization, like Pundit,

```
  def admin_new
    @local_user = User.new
  end

  def admin_create
    @local_user = User.new(user_params)
    @local_user.save
    respond_with(@local_user)
  end
```

where form states:

```
<%= form_for(@local_user, :url => admin_create_users_path) do |f| %>
```

actaully bypasses devise and allows an admin (or any other role) to create users.